# explanation for this statement "list1.sort(key=lambda v: (-v[1], v[0]))"

Tags: sorting, python-2.7

I need explanation for `v:(-v[1],v[0])` in the following python program
What does `v` mean here and what does `-v[1]` and `v[0]` stand for?

```
def top_chars(word, n):
    counts = Counter(word)
    list1 = []
    list1 = counts.most_common()
    list1.sort(key=lambda v: (-v[1], v[0]))
return list1[0:n]
```

For the word="aaaaabbbbcccc"
please explain function v for the given word

Answer (score 0):

The statement `lambda v: (-v[1], v[0])` defines a function.  That function can be assigned to a name and used as a function. Thus:

```
>>> f = lambda v: (-v[1], v[0])
>>> f( (1, 2) )
(-2, 1)
```

`v` can be any list or tuple that has at least two elements.  The function returns a tuple consisting of the negative of the second element followed by the positive of the first element.

**MORE:**  Let's consider the top_chars function when word = "aaaaabbbbcccc".  In this case, the result of `list1 = counts.most_common()` is:

```
[('a', 5), ('c', 4), ('b', 4)]
```

Note that list1 has three elements and each element is a tuple consisting of one character and one number.  The next line, the one with the lambda function, sorts this according to the key given by `f` above.  Let's look at what `f` does to each of the tuples in `list1`:

```
>>> f( ('a', 5) )
(-5, 'a')
>>> f( ('c', 4) )
(-4, 'c')
>>> f( ('b', 4) )
(-4, 'b')
```

To begin, `sort` checks the first elements of the key which, in this case, are the numbers.  The smallest of those numbers is -5.  So `sort` puts ('a', 5) first in the sorted list.  The next smallest value is -4.  But, there are *two* that are ranked at -4.  To choose which one of those two to put next in the list, `sort` has to check with the second value of the key.  In this case, the second values are 'b' and 'c'.  Since 'b' sorts before 'c', `sort` puts ('b', 4) in the list next and ('c', 4) after it.  This explains why the final result is:

```
>>> list1.sort(key=lambda v: (-v[1], v[0]))
>>> list1
[('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`lambda v: (-v[1], v[0])` is a [lambda expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), basically a compact, anonymous function. It is equivalent to:

```
def func(v):
    return (-v[1], v[0])
```

...except that it doesn't have a name, though you can assign names to lambda functions, e.g. `func = lambda v: (-v[1], v[0])`.

Now, the `sort()` method of `list` objects accepts an optional keyword argument `key=`, which should be a function that accepts one argument (which in this case is called `v`). The list will be sorted by the return value of the function that is passed as `key`. What this means is that `list1`, which consists of iterables (e.g. strings, lists, tuples) which we will `v` for now, will be sorted according to the tuple whose first element is negative one times the `1` element of `v` and whose second element is the `0` element of `v`. (For example, if `v = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, then `(-v[1], v[0]) = (-2, 1)`.)

Comment: Can you please explain the same in case of a string word="aaaaabbbbcccc" for the above program.